Automatically creating new account based on new groups in Slurm?
We switched out from PBS Pro to slurm when we upgraded our hardware. With PBS Pro whenever a new user in a new group would get access and PBS Pro would automatically set limits on the group. In Slurm, I don't see the case where they need to be manually created. I'm currently testing a script in the Job Submit Plugin, for adding users when they submit a job. But can't figure out the settings for that to happen based off the group.
 #Check if the username is provided
 if [ -z "$1" ]; then
 echo "Usage: $0 <username>"
 exit 1
 fi
 
 USERNAME=$1
 
 #add the user to Slurm
 sacctmgr -i add user $USERNAME account=<default group>

